# EF4.0 wrong namespace for System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntityType

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-4

i am having a little problem in EF4 code-first (i think that may be a problem only using CF actually).

I am trying to get some info of an entity type from my context metadata using a code similar to this:

```
return (context as System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)
            .ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace
            .GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.CSpace)
            .Where(x => x.FullName == ModelType.FullName)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

ModelType is a parameter wich contains the System.Type of the entity to search for.
It should return a System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntityType instance with the type's metadata.

The model referenced in the DbSet is named MyApp.Models.User and the DbContext class was created under the MyApp.Servicing namespace

Now the problem i am having is that the FullName property of System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntityType is **MyApp.Servicing**.User (O_O) instead of MyApp.Models.User.

*I think it may be that EF is mocking the edm Metadata as i don't have an EDMX in code-first but that's just guessing.*

Any idea of why does this happens? i can solve it another way but would like to know why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your using the wrong Space. CSpace is the top level layer. If you're using the "DataSpace.OSpace" you will get the full qualified class names you are looking for.

```
   var OSpaceEntityType= (context as System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)
     .ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace
     .GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.OSpace)
     .FirstOrDefault(x => x.FullName == ModelType.FullName);
```

...and then to get the corresponding EntityType from the CSpace store:

```
   var CSpaceEntityType= (context as System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)
     .ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace
     .GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.CSpace)
     .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == OSpaceEntityType.Name);
```

Comment: Thanks! now the code looks much better without the mocking.
Know where i can find documentation about this? thanks.

Comment: There is a great book named "Entity Framework 4 in Action". Even though currently there is allready EF6 available this book provides a very good base knowledge and goes deep inside of EF.

Comment: Actually this doesn't work at all, it returns the metadata for the original object. I can get the navigation properties from it but when i ask the NavigationProperty object for it's dependant properties (FK's) with GetDependentProperties now it returns null. With the CSpace it returns the property correctly.
BTW! i am using EF5 not 4, forgot about the upgrade to .net 4.5

Comment: You asked for getting the fully qualified class names. If you want to know how to get NavigationProperties or Foreignkeys you should probably add a new question. And you're right to get these Informations you have to use the CSpace.

Comment: Ok, i create a new question about getting the qualified name of an entity in the CSpace.

Comment: Again: you will never get the full qualified class names from the CSapce since EntityFramework uses their own qualifed names in CSpace. See the improved answer for how to get the EntityType from CSpace using the full qualified class name of your model.